# GCDWebservers background mode not working on device

Tags: ios, swift, gcdwebserver

I'm using GCDWebservers to start a http service. I want it still accept connections in background mode. This is my source code:

```
func startServer (){
    do {
        webServer?.stop()
        webServer?.removeAllHandlers()
            
        try self.webServer?.start(options: [GCDWebServerOption_BonjourName: "", GCDWebServerOption_BonjourType: IMS_DOMAIN, GCDWebServerOption_Port : IMS_SERVICE_PORT, GCDWebServerOption_AutomaticallySuspendInBackground: false])

    } catch {
        print("Start server error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }
        
        
    print("bonjour type", self.webServer?.bonjourType)
}
```

It works on simulator but on real device its not working. This message printout when App goes foreground again:

> dnssd_clientstub read_all(10) DEFUNCT
>
> [ERROR] Bonjour registration
> error -72000 (domain 10)

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to run a web server while your app is in the background (except for the first few minutes at most). See the "GCDWebServer & Background Mode for iOS Apps" section in the GCDWebServer `README` file for the detailed information:

> Typically you must stop any network servers while the app is in the background and restart them when the app comes back to the foreground.